# How do I find where the file for a particular mp3 that I can see in iTunes is?

Tags: itunes

OS 10.6

How do I find where the file for a particular mp3 that I can see in iTunes is?

-- How can I see what folder a track is in?

-- And how do I know which file in that folder it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the song in iTunes and type <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to trigger **Show in Finder**.

Alternatively, you can also right-click the item in iTunes and choose this option from the contextual menu.

From there, you can navigate up the folder hierarchy by holding the <kbd>⌘</kbd>-key and clicking on the folder in the window title bar. You might also want to enable **Show Path bar** in finder.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are three ways:

- Get Info for the track or use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. Navigate to the Summary tab, and it says the file's path in the Finder.
- Right-click the track and select "Show in Finder," and the file will be selected in a new Finder window.
- Open iTunes preferences. Go to the General tab and make sure the "organize files automatically" option is ticked (that isn't the real name of it; I'm not at a computer with iTunes). The iTunes file hierarchy in Finder will be organized according to Artist and Album, making it easy to navigate manually.